# I need to take off the sides " " of character with python

Tags: python

I need to remove the side quotations(") from text. For example if I have [name = "Christophe"] the output will be [name = Christophe]. How can I do this?

i have a parser that parse a file and determines all string between sides(" "), then i stock all this string = names in a list["hely", "christophe" , "jane"] , but i need to remove sides (" ") before create my list, to have this  [hely, christophe , jane]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using `re.sub` here:

```
inp = "name = \"Christophe\""
output = re.sub(r'"(.*?)"', '\\1', inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
name = Christophe
```

Comment: why not `.strip('"')` ? if this is even what OP needs. I highly suspect they print a string to the console and want to "remove" the quotes (much like the python 2 questions that ask how to "remove" the u prefix from unicode strings)

Comment: @DeepSpace `.strip('"')` removes character from start and end of string only so in this case it becomes `'name = "Christophe'`

Comment: @DeepSpace Because `strip` operates on the entire string, and the OP seems (at least to me) to be saying that the input string may have one or more internal words in double quotes.

Comment: @zamir which is supposedly what OP wants. They wrote `need to take off the sides " " `"

Comment: @zamir I think we are missing some info from OP here, the premise of the question as it stands is not very clear

Comment: thank you it works very will ;)

Comment: i have a parser that parse a file and determines all string between sides(" "), then i stock all this string = names in a list["hely", "christophe" , "jane"] , but i need to remove sides (" ") before create my list, to have this  [hely, christophe , jane]